# Switch ItemsSource dynamically in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to switch the itemssource of a treeview depending on a value of a property in my viewmodel. I've tried the code below and the trigger doesnt seem to be firing, can someone tell me where I went wrong?

```
<Window.Resources>  
<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemSource" TargetType="TreeView"> 
       <Style.Triggers>                
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentReportRequested, Mode=TwoWay,     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="TollFree">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding InsertTFSQueryList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />                        
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TreeViewItemSource},  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's still not working. As for the converter, it does no conversion at all, I used it to see what the value of the itemsSource is if/when it fires the data trigger fies. I've taken the converter out of the xaml, however it still doesn't work.

Comment: How can Style resource be served as ItemSource of TreeView? You need to bind it to an `IEnumerable` collection.

Answer (score 2):

Set the **`ItemsSource`** in Style otherwise local set value will always holds priority.

Read more about it here - [**Dependency Property Value Precedence Order**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemSource" TargetType="TreeView"> 
   <!-- Set ItemsSource here but you need to separate Style out of it. -->
   <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
           Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource TreeViewItemSource}, 
                           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                           Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}"/>
   <Style.Triggers>                
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentReportRequested, Mode=TwoWay,
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   Value="TollFree">
         <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding InsertTFSQueryList,
                        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>  
     </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

---

Most importantly you have set ItemsSource to the Style and somewhere in converter, you are converting it to actual value. This is the strangest thing I ever looked. How style is convertible to ItemsSource. Refactor the logic and separate out both so that above XAML works for you.

Answer (score 1):

To solve my issue, I used good-old oop...polymorphism.

I used a polymorphic structure in my ViewModel. Now my ItemsSource is bound to one IEnumerable list which holds the base class...which i can equate to any of the derived types.